# Minimized the htaccess code

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=154
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ www.xyz.com/amit2011/?  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ www.xyz.com/munjal2011/?  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=157
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ www.xyz.com/smayra2011/?  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=158
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ www.xyz.com/vandna2011/?  [R=301,L]
```

I have many more rewrite rules like this based on event_id. As the event_id increases  rewrite rules will be increased propotionaly. Can we merge these above rules, so that i can minimized the code of htaccess.

Comment: Why don't you do that in php?

Comment: I would leave .htaccess as a static set of rules and do all dynamic work in PHP.

Comment: @binary, Can you please tell me how can i do this in PHP?

Comment: sorry, but I cannot provide any code, as I'm not too familiar with mod_rewrite. If it helps - I would redirect **any** `\?event_id=(\d+)` request to a single local PHP page/file which would map numerical ID to those "amit2011" etc and then redirect to "www.xyz.com/amit2011/" or something like that. Though, if you have an access to the server config and can configure VirtualHost, mario's solution might be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for that. But this more or less just separates the rule from the number->pathname map.

```
RewriteMap idmap txt:../../idmap.txt

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ www.xyz.com/${idmap:%1}/?  [R=301,L]
```

And the separate `idmap.txt` would just list:

```
154  amit2011
156  munjal201
157  smayra2011
158  vandna2011
```

It's a simple textual format, and could be auto-generated.

> ---

As pointed out in the other comments, this is also quite simple to implement in a PHP script rather than with just RewriteRules in .htaccess. -- Just replace all your rules with:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ rewrite.php?id=%1  [L]
```

And create a `rewrite.php` script instead:

```
<?php
   $map = array(
      154 => "amit2011",
      156 => "munjal2011",
      157 => "smayra2011",
      158 => "vandna2011",
   );
   header("Location: http://www.xyz.com/{$map[$_GET['id']]}");
   header("Status: 301 Redirect");
```

Comment: That's of course he has an access to the server config, because RewriteMap is not available in standalone .htaccess.

Comment: mario, first line(RewriteMap idmap txt:../../idmap.txt) give me internal server error. can you please tell me what i do?

Comment: @munjal: Two things. Most importantly you need to set this directive in the VirtualHost section, not in the .htaccess (as @akond pointed out). Secondly, you need to specify an absolute pathname. The `../../idmap.txt` should be `/var/www/yourhost/idmap.txt` or something.

Comment: @mario, not getting your point(second point is fine). I am doing this locally. Can you please more elaborate this point.

Comment: @munjal: Server configuration. You need to edit your `httpd.conf` or `vhost.conf`. The `RewriteMap` directive may only be used there. It cannot be used in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @mario, about the `header()` function - you can specify status as the 3rd parameter of `header()`, i.e., `header("Location: {$url}", true, 301)` would be enough.

Comment: The rewriteMap can also be converted to a hashmap file, if there is no logic in the routing process it will be the fastest solution, faster than a PHP process for sure (but harder to maitain, maybe?)

Comment: @binaryLV: True, I always forget that. On the plus side, with a manual `Status:` line you can set silly messages (since they're free-form). In this case it's redundant since PHP sets it already when it sees a `Location:` header.

Comment: @mario, last thing, can you provide me the lines of code which i have to written in the httpd.conf file.(thanx in advance)

Comment: @munjal: Just the `RewriteMap` must go into the `httpd.conf`. The RewriteCond/RewriteRule can go into the `.htaccess` asis.